# Eigenvalues of sum of Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

..........................................................................................................................................................
[image]
..........................................................................................................................................................

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts and can share what you have tried and where you are confused? Regards

Comment: (http://yahiasite.webs.com/answer.PNG).

Answer (score 0):

[Courant-Fischer minimax principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) would be useful. By the way, you should explain how $(1)$ or $(2)$ follow from their preceding lines. Also, strict inequalities in $(1)$ and $(2)$ should be replaced by nonstrict inequalities (e.g. equality holds in $(1)$ when $B=0$) and you should tag the last equation as $(3)$ rather than $(2)$.